# ggplot multiple manual shape series

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have chart that is showing the change in a risk variable through time. Currently, it has two `geom_point` series, one to show the risk level for each month and one to display the change in risk level between the initial and final value ('Jan-20' data point arrows in the snippet below):

[image]

I would like to vary the shape of each of the risk level datapoints to show an additional series of data. However, as the 'change in risk' data point is currently defined using a `scale_shape_manual` argument, I seem unable to do this.

When adding a second `scale_shape_manual` argument I get the following error code and the arrow shapes are not displayed. `Scale for 'shape' is already present. Adding another scale for 'shape', which will replace the existing scale.`

The code generating the chart with the error is shown below. The `sh_pal_all` vector contains all information for defining all the shapes used in the two series.

Is there any way to manually define two separate shape aesthetics in the same ggplot object?

```
sh_pal_all <- c("Up" = "\U2191", "No Change" = "\U2194", "Down" = "\U2193", "A1" = "circle", "B1" = "square", "C1" = "diamond", "D1" = "triangle", "E1" = "circle")

ggplot(data = meltdf2_all, aes(x = Month, y = variable, group = variable)) +
  geom_line(linetype = "dashed", colour = "grey") +
  geom_point(aes(colour = meltdf2_all$colour, size = 3, shape = meltdf2_all$accommodation)) +
  geom_point(data = melt_change_all, aes(shape = value, size = 3)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = pal_all, limits = names(pal_all), guide_legend("Risk Level")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = sh_pal_all[1:3], limits = names(sh_pal_all[1:3]), guide_legend("Latest Change")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = sh_pal_all[4:8], limits = names(sh_pal_all[4:8]), guide_legend("Accomodation Type")) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month" , date_labels = "%b-%y") +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "darkgrey"), axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(0.2,0.70),
        legend.key.size = unit(1.5,"line"),
        legend.box = "horizontal") + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 3)), shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 5))) +
  scale_size(guide = "none")
```

Comment: Can you post your data so there's a completely reproducible example? If not, what happens if you combine the two `scale_shape_manual` layers? 
`scale_shape_manual(values = sh_pal_all, limits = names(sh_pal_all))`

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of scale_shape_manual? It may work if you put them right after the geom_point they should be defining. Also, you could try to save a first plot as an object and then add another layer of geom point with the respective scale_shape_manual.